# Stablising berry coulis

Tags: food-preservation

I have made a coulis with strawberries and raspberries, 500gms of each with half a cup of sugar and the juice of one lemon.  I boiled it for 15 minutes, then pureed it, put it through a fine sieve to remove all seeds, then bottled it and sealed with a tamper-proof lid.  My question is, how do I make this coulis shelf stable, are the ingredients I am using enough to ensure this will be fine until opened, then into the fridge?

Comment: You have not made this shelf stable at all, boiling for 15 minutes, then bottling it will allow foodborne pathogens in your coulis. You need to use a canning method, probably pressure canning as you likely don't have enough acid for water bath canning. [This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28013/can-pressure-canning-be-replaced-water-bath-canning) has some details.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend freezing portions of your finished coulis into some sandwich or freezer bags, and pulling them as you require.